# Bitrix веб-формы, кодировка

Tags: кодировка, битрикс

Использую модуль веб-формы, при заполнении которых на сайте, создал шаблон отправки на почту сообщений. Почему некоторые поля не отправляются кириллицей, а судя по всему уходят в `UTF-8`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отправка происходит в окне `fancybox`, код отправки:

```
    $('#form-order').on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    var $form = $(this),
        action = $form.attr('action'),
        data = $form.serializeArray();

    e.preventDefault();

    data.push({
        name: 'web_form_submit',
        value: 'y'
    });

    $.post(action, data, function(data) {
        $.fancybox($(data));
    });

    return false;
});
```

Основной шаблон сайта использует `windows-1251`, как думаете в чем могут быть проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.post()` всегда по умолчанию отправляет данные в UTF-8.

Подробнее об этом в [документации jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Теоретически, можно попытаться переопределить, но спецификация W3C XMLHttpRequest требует отправки данных в UTF: браузер может проигнорировать настройку.

Так что исходите из того, что данные в вашу форму придут в UTF-8.